# Having a error when passing model item in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[LabSys.NEWLabSys.TestDataLog]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LabSys.NEWLabSys.TestDataViewModel]'.
```

This is the error I am getting when running the controller.

Here is my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index(int? searchTestNumber, int? searchProject, string testType, string engineer, string technician, string testStall)
    {           

         var data = from m in db.TestDataLogs
                        select m;   

        var testTypeL = new List<string>();
        var engineerL = new List<string>();
        var testStallL = new List<string>();
        var technicianL = new List<string>();

        var testStallQry = from z in db.TestDataLogs
                           orderby z.TestStall
                           select z.TestStall;

        var technicianQry = from d in db.TestDataLogs
                            orderby d.Technician
                            select d.Technician;

        var testTypeQry = from d in db.TestDataLogs
                     orderby d.TestType
                     select d.TestType;

        var engineerQry = from p in db.TestDataLogs
                      orderby p.Engineer
                      select p.Engineer;

        technicianL.AddRange(technicianQry.Distinct());
        testStallL.AddRange(testStallQry.Distinct());
        testTypeL.AddRange(testTypeQry.Distinct());
        engineerL.AddRange(engineerQry.Distinct());

        ViewBag.testType = new SelectList(testTypeL);
        ViewBag.engineer = new SelectList(engineerL);
        ViewBag.technician = new SelectList(technicianL);
        ViewBag.testStall = new SelectList(testStallL);

        string searchTestNumber1 = Convert.ToString(searchTestNumber);
        string searchProject1 = Convert.ToString(searchProject);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTestNumber1))
        {
            data = data.Where(s => s.TestNumber.Equals(searchTestNumber));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchProject1))
        {
            data = data.Where(x => x.Project.Equals(searchProject));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(testType))
        {
            data = data.Where(z => z.TestType == testType);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(engineer))
        {
            data = data.Where(z => z.Engineer == engineer);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(testStall))
        {
            data = data.Where(z => z.TestStall == testStall);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(technician))
        {
            data = data.Where(z => z.Technician == technician);
        }


        return View(data);
```

And here is the start of my view

```
@model IEnumerable<LabSys.NEWLabSys.TestDataViewModel>

 <label id="recordId" style="display: none"></label>
 <style type="text/css">
   .ui-autocomplete.ui-menu {
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: black;
    width: 100px;
}
</style>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "TestData", FormMethod.Get))
{ 
<form id="addpartForm">
    <div id="newPartForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <label>Test Number</label>
                @Html.TextBox("searchTestNumber")
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <label>Project</label>
            @Html.TextBox("searchProject")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <label>Test Type: </label>
            @Html.DropDownList("testType", "All")                
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <label for="parttype">Test Date</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="date" class="form-control" />
                <em class="text-muted">Choose your date</em>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <label>End Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" />
            <em class="text-muted">Choose your end date</em>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <label>Engineer</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("engineer", "All")             
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <label>Technician</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("technician","All")                   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <label for="inventoryType">Test Stall</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("testStall", "All")                
        </div>
    </div>    
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="filter">Search!</button>
</div>
```

}

And then last is my viewmodel

```
namespace LabSys.NEWLabSys
{
public class TestDataViewModel
    {
        public TestDataLog TestData { get; set; }

    }
 }
```

So I think it may be something wrong with my IEnumerable  related to the controller but I am not sure.
Thanks so much!

Comment: `data` is of type `IEnumerable<TestDataLogs>` but your view expecting your ViewModel.  You'll have to do a conversion or make your view accept the `TestDataLogs`

Answer (score 1):

As error says you are passing data of wrong type to your view. Try:

```
return View(data.ToList());
```

**Update 1.**

First time I misread something. So problem is that in your View you are expecting `IEnumerable<LabSys.NEWLabSys.TestDataViewModel>` but from code you are passing `DbQuery<LabSys.NEWLabSys.TestDataLog>`. So even ToList won't fix that issue as you need to make a conversion try something like that:

```
return View(data.Select(x => new TestDataViewModel { TestData = x }).ToList());
```

Comment: @EliHellmer Are you sure that SAME error? Can you paste that error message there?

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LabSys.NEWLabSys.TestDataLog]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LabSys.NEWLabSys.TestDataViewModel]'.

Comment: @EliHellmer also from code you posted I can't see where you using that model. So if you not using that error you mentioned can be fixed by removing model List<LabSys.NEWLabSys.TestDataViewModel>

Comment: Okay so are you saying that i could remove the @model, and just use my TestDataLogs List? And thank you.

Comment: @EliHellmer I updated my answer again after you shown your viewmodel - that should work. But regarding to remove: what is a point of passing that model into a view if you are not using that? or you just haven't added code where you using your TestDataViewModel?

Comment: I have deleted TestDataViewModel, and am working on a new model/set up. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

convert data to data.ToList()

and may be in your view change the following:

```
@model List<LabSys.NEWLabSys.TestDataViewModel>
```

Comment: I changed the return value and also the @model in my view and it gives me this weird exception:

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LabSys.NEWLabSys.TestDataLog]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LabSys.NEWLabSys.TestDataViewModel]'.

Comment: It's because you are not passing ViewModel (TestDataViewModel) in your View .... infact you are passing your Entity Model i.e. TestDataLogs ... Change you view to @@model List<TestDataLogs> ... make sure you have the right reference to Entity model